# Specs randomly fail with ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant SimpleForm::Inputs::TextFullscreenInput)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, eager-loading

I have some specs failing randomly. I bisected the problem...

```
rspec --bisect=verbose --seed 40467
```

and RSpec gave me the following "minimal reproduction command":

```
rspec ./spec/features/file_upload_spec.rb[2:1] ./spec/features/pages/edit_spec.rb[1:1,1:2] ./spec/features/pages/new_spec.rb[1:1,1:2] --seed 40467
```

When inspecting the test logs, for every failing spec, the following exception is raised:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (uninitialized constant SimpleForm::Inputs::TextFullscreenInput):
    16:         = panel.body do
    17:           = f.input :title
    18:           = f.input :navigation_title
    19:           = f.input :content, as: :text_fullscreen_with_pastable_images
    20:           = f.input :notes, as: :text_fullscreen_with_pastable_images
    21: 
    22:   == render 'images/images', f: f
```

The respective custom input lives in `app/inputs`. I have `config.eager_load = false` set (default) for testing. So should I set it to `true`? Or is there a better way to fix this problem?

The problem seems to be that `TextFullscreenWithPastableImagesInput` extends `SimpleForm::Inputs::TextFullscreenInput` which itself isn't loaded yet.

Here's the repository: https://github.com/jmuheim/base/tree/features/paste_nested_images

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had this definition of the class:

```
class TextFullscreenWithPastableImagesInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::TextFullscreenInput
```

But `TextFullscreenInput` itself isn't in the `SimpleForm::Inputs` namespace, it's only defined as:

```
class TextFullscreenInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::TextInput
```

So when removing the namespace it worked:

```
class TextFullscreenWithPastableImagesInput < TextFullscreenInput
```